# Emacs Save Buffer Keybinding?

Tags: emacs

Is there an alternative to `C-x C-s` for saving in Emacs? My VT520 terminal uses `C-s` for scroll lock and gives weird behavior. Alternatively can I reprogram it or reprogram the VT520 to another keybinding.

Answer (score 4):

you could run it manually with `M-x save-buffer`. But I would try to fix your terminal, as you also miss `search-forward` if you don't have `C-s`, which is one of the preferred commands to navigate buffers among emacs users.

Answer (score 0):

I disable XON/XOFF in my .bashrc (should work for any shell, though maybe not every terminal):

```
# this stops C-s from freezing the terminal
if [ "$TERM" != "dumb" ] ; then
    stty -ixon
fi
```

Comment: I am not sure if this would work with an actual physical terminal? I am using a real Digital Equipment Corporation VT520 terminal not emulating one. Will test it just in case.

Comment: I believe that the VT520 terminal is responding to C-s with scroll lock before it ever reaches the computer (an Old DEC VAX running OpenBSD). Will test nevertheless.

Comment: I didn't realize it was a physical terminal.  stty probably won't work, but there must be some way to configure it.

Comment: http://web.mit.edu/dosathena/doc/www/ek-vt520-rm.pdf talks about a DECSFC command, which can be used to turn off flow control.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own key bindings in Emacs for any command. For instance, to make <kbd>CTRL+x CTRL+z</kbd> an additional key binding for `save-buffers`, put the following in your .emacs file:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-z") 'save-buffers)
```

Just be careful which keybindings you choose: some modes might overwrite them.

See also [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html#Init-Rebinding) for more details.